# PHP - $.POST Twice through two files

Tags: php, jquery, syntax-error

Shortened Aim: To pass a variable via $.POST to a PHP file (get.php), and for get.php to $.POST the variable again to db.php.

**My Problem**

I'm trying to follow the model-view-controller design pattern within my PHP code.

I'll have three pages:

1. **index.php** - The GUI (basically HTML and DIV tags)
2. **get.php** - The hidden php which serves code via AJAX + POST to divs in index.php
3. **db.php** - The database connection part

[image: explanation image]

*Basically, I want to receive a response through two POST requests*

So far I have index.php POSTING to get.php and requesting certain data, which is returned via and updated via AJAX and jQuery for animation.

Here's a code snippet:

```
function get(div,id,opt_username) { 
$.post('get.php', { request: id },
function(response) {
    // In this order, first fadeout div
    $(div).fadeOut(600, function() {

        // If we pass a username as optional parameter...
        if (opt_username) { 
            //Prepend username onto response
            response = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Welcome " + username + response;   
        }

        // Then get the response back HIDDEN
        $(div).html(response).hide(function() {
                // Once completed, parse with XFBML so everything renders
                FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(div));
                // Only after everything's parsed do we fade back in
                $(div).fadeIn(1100, function() {}); 

        });
    });
});
};
```

Now I can do POST requests to get.php, but if I try and do the same thing within get.php to post to db.php (to perform database operations) this just does not seem to work.

**My Aim**

index.php **->** request data **->** get.php **->** request db connection **->** db.php **->** return data **->** get.php **->** return data **->** index.php

This will allow me to switch the database layer out with another one. For example I'm currently using RDBMS but I would like to switch to XML / RDFXML in the future, meaning all I have to do is switch out the db.php for another one and everything will still work, keeping in-line with the MVC.

**My Questions**

1. First and foremost, can I actually make a POST to a page to make **another** POST and if so, why am I getting the error below?
2. Am I going about the Model View Controller approach the correct way

**Further Explanation**

Here is a code snippet in get.php (the second page) which throws an error:

```
$.post('db.php', { test: 2 },
    function(response) {} );
```

Error thrown:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting T_VARIABLE or '$'
```

**Conclusion**

I simply can't get index.php to post to get.php, in turn posting to db.php.

Comment: You can post your answer as an actual answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implementing model-view-controller does not mean you have to create HTTP requests to communicate between these layers. Simply include the file using `include` or `require`. The seperation already exists by having different files.

Comment: If I did an include for my db.php with database connections then my UI at the front would show the functions and code I'm calling to grab the database information wouldn't it? Therefore, putting the UI at the front, the logic in another PHP and the db connection stuff in the final PHP is good, where as having some of this code in the original index.php means that everyone will be able to see the functions and methods called easily?

Comment: @Jimbo: What do you mean by "show" the functions? These functions are never visible to the web client. They might be visible to the programmer by the fact you include it. But that's the reason why people use object oriented programming and do now mess up the global scope.

Comment: Well if I include db.php, and within this PHP is code for connecting to the DB, then someone could just head over to db.php and view my source (db location, username, what is being sent etc). Where as if I do things by POST then everything's hidden.. right? :) Forgot to add: if I do it your way then when I come to change the DB 'layer' technology from RDBMS to say XML / RDFXML then I will have to open my index.php and mess around with everything, where as if I have it in it's own db.php then I can just switch over the db.php without having to touch my view (index.php) or my logic (get.php).

Comment: No, sorry. PHP file are processed by the server, because they contain a set of PHP instructions. The are never sent to a client as plain text unless you have a serious missconfiguration of your server. BTW: never consider a file inaccessible by the fact that it is not known by the user.

Comment: I thought I'd come back, a year later, to explain that you were absolutely right with this simple answer - now understanding MVC much much better. Vote to delete my answer would you, it's complete rubbish. Can't believe I suggested cURL. Thanks!

Comment: @Jimbo: Great to hear it help you learning something. Most people are looking for ready to use solutions instead of getting assistance in learning something new.

Answer (score 2):

Do you *have* to make two `post`s?

I don't know what your files look like, but right now I'm guessing that they are all regular php files which you are duplicating for each of your pages when you need to implement that page's functionality, so my answer will try to fit into that but as I said, I don't know what your files actually look like so this may not fit into the way you are working.

That said, based on the way that I *think* you are using your files this is what I would suggest.

Instead of trying to make two posts between the pages, why not just pass the $_POST array to a method in a class?

For example (In pseudo code):

**Your index.php (posts to get.php via AJAX):**

```
<form action="/uses/ajax/to/post/to/get.php" method="post" name="data_form" id="data_form">
    <input type="text" name="data" id="data" />
    <input type="text" name="more_data" id="more_data" />
    <input type="submit" value="Post this data" />
</form>

<script>
    // Your ajax post code here
</script>
```

**Your get.php:**

```
<?php
$post_data = isset($_POST) ? $_POST : die('No post data was sent');

include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/Model_Object.php');

$Model_Object = new Model_Object();

// This would echo your response for the ajax
echo $Model_Object->create_something($post_data);
```

Then instead of having just db.php you can create a Model class (which is included in your get.php):

**Model_Object.php:**

```
<?php
class Model_Object {
    public function create_something($post_data) {
        $data = isset($post_data['data']) ? $post_data['data'] : '';
        $more_data = isset($post_data['more_data']) ? $post_data['more_data'] : '';

        // MySQL query here
        $success = true;

        if($success) {
            return 'Completed';
        }

        return 'Failed';
    }

    public function create_something_else($post_data) {
        return 'This can do a different MySQL query';
    }
}
```

It's not the best way of doing it, but given your explanation of your own code and based on the way I think your code is working this might be a solution for you.

As for going about the MVC approach in the correct way, I don't know if this is how it is best done but, when I write MVC applications from scratch I setup a `.htaccess` file to route all requests to the root `index.php`, which would, from the URI decide which `Controller` object to create and which method within that `Controller` to execute.

That method might for example contain some code to display a view, or create a `Model` object to interact with the database.

If a `Model` were to be created then it would pass back any relevant information to the `Controller` and the `Controller` would do what it needs to do from there.

For example if I went to `/my_controller/my_action` then the index.php file would create the `My_Controller` object if it existed, and if it existed try to execute a method within that object called `my_action`.

I hope this has been of some help to you and I'm sorry if I have mis-understood.

Comment: I appreciate the length and effort it took you to post this, so thanks for that. However, what I was really looking for was the ability to POST to one page, which POSTs to another, which returns all the way back to the beginning. Using classes is going away from what I'm after, but I'll mark yours as a useful answer anyway.